# Force request to use /etc/hosts

Tags: node.js, proxy, request, hosts

I basically have an internal url that is mapped to an ip address in the /etc/hosts file. When I do a ping on the url the correct internal ip address is returned. Problems arise when I rely on the `request` node module:

/etc/hosts:

```
123.123.123.123 fakeurl.com
```

app.js:

403 error:

```
var request = require('request');
request('http://fakeurl.com/', function (error, response, body) {
     console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
     console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
     console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the page.
});
```

works 200 code:

```
var request = require('request');
request('http://123.123.123.123/', function (error, response, body) {
     console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
     console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
     console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the page.
});
```

Is there a way to force the dns mapping within the node app?

Comment: Can you try this using the http module instead? The http module should resolve according to /etc/hosts.

Comment: I wish it was this simple. I'm tied to the request module because it is actually being performed by another node module. I just narrowed down the issue of why its occurring and was hoping to find a way to bypass it.

Comment: I am facing this same problem. And I have no idea why Node.js keep making request ignore hosts file. Have you found any solution bro?

Comment: I actually had to make a pull request to the git repo that was causing the issue. Luckily the owner accepted my changes. Wish I had a better answer for you.

Answer (score 4):

The default DNS resolution method used by node ([`dns.lookup()`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/dns.html#dns_dns_lookup_hostname_options_callback)) uses the system resolver, which almost always takes /etc/hosts into account.

The difference here has nothing to do with DNS resolution per se, but most likely instead has to do with the value used for the HTTP `Host` field. In the first request `Host: fakeurl.com` will be sent to the HTTP server at 123.123.123.123, whereas in the second request `Host: 123.123.123.123` will be sent to the HTTP server at 123.123.123.123. The server may interpret these two requests differently depending on their configuration.

So you will need to manually resolve the address if you want to use the IP address as the HTTP `Host` header field value. For example:

```
require('dns').lookup('fakeurl.com', (err, ip) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  request(`http://${ip}/`, (error, response, body) => {
    // ...
  });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't always resolve into an IP, e.g. when a TLS hostname check is made at the other end.